# How can I iterate over Record keys in a proper type-safe way?

Tags: typescript

Let's build an example record over some properties.

```
type HumanProp = 
    | "weight"
    | "height"
    | "age"

type Human = Record<HumanProp, number>;

const alice: Human = {
    age: 31,
    height: 176,
    weight: 47
};
```

For each property, I also want add a human-readable label:

```
const humanPropLabels: Readonly<Record<HumanProp, string>> = {
    weight: "Weight (kg)",
    height: "Height (cm)",
    age: "Age (full years)"
};
```

Now, using this Record type and defined labels, I want to iterate over two record with the same key types.

```
function describe(human: Human): string {
    let lines: string[] = [];
    for (const key in human) {
        lines.push(`${humanPropLabels[key]}: ${human[key]}`);
    }
    return lines.join("\n");
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Readonly<Record<HumanProp, string>>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Readonly<Record<HumanProp, string>>'.
```

How can I implement this functionality in Typescript properly?

To clarify, the solution I'm looking for, regardless of whether it will use `Record` type, plain objects, types, classes, interfaces or something else, should have following properties:

1. When I want to define a new property, I only need to do it in one place (like in HumanProp above), and don't repeat myself.
2. After I define a new property, all the places where I should add a new value for this property, like when I'm creating `alice`, or `humanPropLabels`, light up **type errors** at compilation time, not in runtime errors.
3. Code that iterates over all properties, like `describe` function, should remain unchanged when I create a new property.

Is it even possible to implement something like that with Typescript's type system?

Comment: This seems to be related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32811

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the right way to do this is to create an immutable array of the key names and give it a narrow type so that the compiler recognizes it as containing [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) instead of just `string`.  This is easiest with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const humanProps = ["weight", "height", "age"] as const;
// const humanProps: readonly ["weight", "height", "age"]
```

Then you can define `HumanProp` in terms of it:

```
type HumanProp = typeof humanProps[number];
```

And the rest of your code should work more or less as-is, except that when you iterate over keys you should use your immutable array above instead of `Object.keys()`:

```
type Human = Record<HumanProp, number>;

const alice: Human = {
   age: 31,
   height: 176,
   weight: 47
};

const humanPropLabels: Readonly<Record<HumanProp, string>> = {
   weight: "Weight (kg)",
   height: "Height (cm)",
   age: "Age (full years)"
};

function describe(human: Human): string {
    let lines: string[] = [];
    for (const key of humanProps) { // <-- iterate this way
        lines.push(`${humanPropLabels[key]}: ${human[key]}`);
    }
    return lines.join("\n");
}
```

The reason not to use `Object.keys()` is that the compiler can't verify that an object of type `Human` will *only* have the keys declared in `Human`.  Object types in TypeScript are open/extendible, not closed/[exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  This allows interface extension and class inheritance to work:

```
interface SuperHero extends Human {
   powers: string[];
}
declare const captainStupendous: SuperHero;
describe(captainStupendous); // works, a SuperHero is a Human
```

You wouldn't want `describe()` to explode because you pass in a `SuperHero`, a special type of `Human` with an extra `powers` property.  So instead of using `Object.keys()` which correctly produces `string[]`, you should use the hardcoded list of known properties so that code like `describe()` will ignore any extra properties if they are present.

---

And, if you add an element to `humanProps`, you'll see errors where you want while `describe()` will be unchanged:

```
const humanProps = ["weight", "height", "age", "shoeSize"] as const; // added prop

const alice: Human = { // error! 
   age: 31,
   height: 176,
   weight: 47
};

const humanPropLabels: Readonly<Record<HumanProp, string>> = { // error!
   weight: "Weight (kg)",
   height: "Height (cm)",
   age: "Age (full years)"
};

function describe(human: Human): string { // okay
   let lines: string[] = [];
   for (const key of humanProps) {
      lines.push(`${humanPropLabels[key]}: ${human[key]}`);
   }
   return lines.join("\n");
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ANgEyQbwFBIPgHtgoAXJACwFcwRgAFAJyJiiQF4kBtAIgHcIASwDmlMrwA0SXpWFiJ03iBEReAXSQh2xUmQDc+AmQCeMZAAla9Zq05JT5ogDMq1xizbdgtAEYQmdUMCBzNLd3sAJQhiJgwAHis6D1ZpHzB-JgA+QyMkXXItNCFEAC4kJPp7PBCQlQhygGYARkk8kLlRcXLmgHYANjbagkEusnKAFl68gF99JFw8gooaZNsYABkQfzQocuiQDBI0E3jo2ITKlJhpciYhYBEsrOr2kflumQB1D4oACgA1iIAJRSN5UX7lXgWX5IP7wMCgobDepQgCCqjhzmoaDQSBMEBATCgoNmuRC2OA8DIQhISAw0Hg938f1W9HKV2B5TuDxEOHBaAgFGKwGg3LI90e3E0XGlwWGziITDhyyQAIgJiQLjca08JP5w1qIugADoYNQoJQ-gADAAk2DZ1y2Oyg3HVJnUM3K9sdbo1nutwPltRm4KYQuoTGASGNUBNACsiA8-rwADrAXhB2aLEIPMgBZwIZAAZWo5iYMJYSAgAA988AMOwrgbhjAiIJieLJSI5dmQgz4GgichVfAQDAyCAHsWyGWIA2iBbyqXy5WiMGGVAmUIWWOJ1PgDO5wuLUGkAB6c9IfhKgFQaQgJArgJrpBCdiPpIkXCh3CgSCwEWSAAHIQPwLb5CQhSOus7CygIvxSDInQKEhyiqGhlpEBAxZCAAXmomjaJBejBo44S6nYXDkdqMF6t4fgBEEeTkRUERcOcSqXO46xpIx2TkoQUEUCAxRlGxyTVBeV4BCwTAAITgqiSAtMitQoZ8fSDOCowKJM0whHMOZCXoOo2J4zoQLs+yEkcwAnGcMRcYkPGeLcEq8s8UmXtWTByYphq6Z8vA-GMcJAki4IaeMMgwmF8KImChrKbwGLIH82K4vihLEqShmCUglLUrS0abtuLKOhy7hckgPKPBBISCsKDxirVHlSjKPDMYairKvCwlqhqWquHRrD6jUhoELGZoWladoOq5rCWbsfoel6SA+u4q0Blmhqhoa4azlGMYtXGibJmmGa7QQoa-kAA)

Comment: I ran into a bit of a problem with this solution down the line when I tried to use them with product types. If I define separate `Human` and `Super` type, how would I iterate through the `type SuperHuman = Human & Super` type properties?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out: `const superHumanProps = ([] as SuperHumanProp[]).concat(humanProps, superHumanProps);`

Comment: If you want to make sure a pure type in your declaration file stays in sink with the string literal workaround, this might add value:
// in .d.ts
export type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
// in .ts 
export const iterableKeys =  ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
export type IterableKeys = typeof iterableKeys[number];
let safetyCheck1: Record<Keys, number> = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
let safetyCheck2: Record<IterableKeys, number> = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
safetyCheck1 = safetyCheck2;
safetyCheck2 = safetyCheck1;

Answer (score 7):

There are good answers provided to this specific question above, but, in my case, my mistake was trying to use a Record type in the first place.

Taking a step back, if you are trying to map keys to values and iterate over them in a type-safe way, you might be better off using a Map:

```js
type Test = 'harry' | 'sam' | 'alex';

const m = new Map<Test, number>();

for (const [k, v] of m)
{
    // this won't compile because k is type Test
    if (k === 'foo') { console.log(v); }
}
```

The downside of this is, unlike a Record, a Map cannot guarantee all the keys in type Test have been mapped... but I ended up on this page as a novice trying to figure out how to iterate over a Record<number, string>, and obviously my mistake was reaching for the Record type in the first place.

Anyways, this insight helped me. Maybe it'll help someone else.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to bend to use Typescript... other times it's probably better to make Typescript bend for you.  I would opt for something  MUCH simpler than trying to maintain some concrete string array instance (and keep it in sync with the interfaces).  I wouldn't use `HumanProps`.  In my opinion this simple change (adding `as keyof Human`) is the best way to avoid your error (and IMO it even makes the code more readable):

```
function describe2(human: Human): string {
    let lines: string[] = [];
    for (const key in human) {
        lines.push(`${humanPropLabels[key as keyof Human]}: ${human[key as keyof Human]}`);
    }
    return lines.join("\n");
}
```

Comment: Remember when people said the dynamic typing of Javascript would save us SO much time???  Not so much.  How many hours have I spent on strange Typescript problems...?