# Why does TypeScript not throw an error when the function argument type is mismatched?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's a very basic example to demonstrate what I mean:

```js
type Payload = {
    id: number;
}

type GreatPayload = {
    id: number;
    surprise: 4;
}

type Action = (payload: Payload) => void;

const action: Action = payload => null;

const payload: GreatPayload = {
    id: 1,
    surprise: 4,
};

action({ id: 1, surprise: 4 }); // <== as expected, this errors out because `surprise` is not present in `Payload`

action(payload); // <== my question is, why does this not throw an error?
```

(And the [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEygXigbwLABQUxUAlmgFxQB2ArgLYBGEATgNyEC+hhokUAcRYQ4weElQZs+IiXJU6TVh1nEAzrRZgWpNRCoAWFdwK9w0AIIBjYKWTUsUABRgEKdFXHu0ASiwA+KAA3ZHIVQit7NWAoOBs7aiprW3tHVwl0AJpaRERwgkjqaKh07yohETE3SUcZEjJKKABGABpCeo0tHT1DNoJOfLiU6iccBqpWqE7tXX0oAyhOH0H4+xdq9GWgA) for an editable example.)

Why does `action(payload)` not throw an error when the type of `payload` that's passed in (`GreatPayload`) is clearly a mismatch for the function argument type `Payload`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497299/typescript-prevent-assignment-of-object-with-more-properties-than-is-specified)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are open/extendible, not closed/[exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  That means it's acceptable for an object of type `X` to contain more properties than the definition of `X` mentions. You can think of object type definitions as describing the *known* properties of the type, while having no implications about *possible unknown* properties.

This openness is important because it allows interface extension and class inheritance.  Your type definitions are nearly identical to

```
interface Payload {
    id: number;
}

interface GreatPayload extends Payload {
    surprise: 4;
}
```

And here you can see that `GreatPayload` *is* a special type of `Payload`.  It has an extra property, but it's still a `Payload`.  Same thing with class inheritance:

```
class Foo {
    a = "foo";
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    b = "bar";
}
```

A `Bar` instance *is* a `Foo`:

```
const f: Foo = new Bar(); // okay
```

---

The only place where the TypeScript compiler treats object types as if they were exact is when you create a brand new object literal and assign it to a type.  This is documented in the TypeScript Handbook as "[Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)"... and you can also look at [microsoft/TypeScript#3755](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755), the GitHub issue that discusses the need for this behavior; misspelling optional properties would be completely uncaught errors without some sort of key checking like this.  But it's not a full implementation of exact types.

---

So when you call this:

```
action({ id: 1, surprise: 4 });  // error
```

you are passing in a fresh object literal that contains an unexpected `surprise` property, and the compiler warns via excess property checks.  But when you call this:

```
action(payload);  // okay
```

you are passing in the variable `payload`, which is not an object literal itself, and the object literal you assigned to `payload` is no longer "fresh".  So no excess property checks happen and you get no warning.

---

If you really want to see exact types implemented so that you could easily ask for `Exact<Payload>`, you might want to go to [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) and give it a , and possibly even describe your use case if it's particularly compelling.

But given that the current behavior is probably not going anywhere for a while, your time might be better spent trying to work *with* open types instead of against them.  Consider writing your code so that it doesn't mind if an object has more properties than specified in the type declaration.  If you're just indexing into the object with known keys, you'll be fine.  If you're iterating through object properties, don't use `Object.keys()` or `for..in` loops if your code would explode on unexpected properties.  Instead, think about iterating through known keys from a hardcoded array (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829651/how-can-i-iterate-over-record-keys-in-a-proper-type-safe-way/61829933#61829933) for one way to do this).  The idea is to make your code immune to unknown extra properties so that you don't care if someone gives you a `GreatPayload` when you're expecting just a `Payload`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmyA3gLABQylyw+AXMiAK4C2ARtANzkC+55okWIhQBxKBDhh02PIQgAPSCHwBnNJlwFi5KshWMoAByjAVEegBYuZXmXIIscFWoBiOHNopU4yALzIAIhh3AOtuZHtHZ2QAITgoZAUlVWQ3D1IvSlY-QNZ40J57HBAVMGQYejSckAgAd1j4gAoASmtyMAxDFABBBDBgYpzGww1ZemlNfGa-AD5kADccGjayBGLS5ER+4vpe7ZAhw3HRgmnfOYzdQwA6ZcK7VfWykZkCejEJKRPCf0uqGnoAEYADQ6Kj6IwmMyWUE2FZbAYgRpEah0ZAgvQGYymczICzIbitZAAemJ5XEKgAFsgcKwAFYQPrILDAQRwLDAxLyJDRYw4LpQDrIBCUxkAa1AAHNyAjisNvkSSWSQDgyjAKZTOSqyiLxRBCMEEgoeWo+QL+hAVNcgA)

Comment: I think the most confusing part for me is the fact that the same object - one as an object literal and the other as an object, when passed to a typed function yields different results with the compiler - it would have been easier if the behaviour was consistent.

Comment: I've always thought that we should be as precise as possible when describing shapes of objects, so this particular nuance really threw me off, but perhaps as you said, there's no harm passing in additional things that aren't used, the resulting function can simply ignore them. I'll have another think about how that applies to my current problem - thanks for the thorough explanation and advice!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Satck Overflow!

Types in TS are not actually "types", but rather type alias. According to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) type alias are sometimes similar to interfaces.

In Typescript, instances that implement interfaces can have additional properties and still be valid. Thus, the compiler throws no error on your `action` type with the *GreetPayload* instance as an input.