# Why can we assign an interface with more properties to another interface with less?

Tags: typescript

I expect the following code to not compile. The reason is that when assigning `person` and `expert` to `people`, the `person` constant satisfies the type for the `people` constant which should be `Person` type. However, the `expert` has a `skills` filed that doesn't exist on `Person` type.

Yet it does compile.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age?: number; 
}

interface Developer {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
  skills: string[];
}

const person: Person = {
  name: 'john doe',
  age: 20,
};

const expert: Developer = {
  name: 'jane doe',
  skills: ['javascript', 'react']
};

const people: Person[] = [ person, expert ];

console.log(people);
```

Comment: `Developer` is structurally a sub type of `Person`. Any `Developer` is a `Person` so you can assign a developer where a person is expected. This is a fundamental tenant of OOP. (The exception to this in TS is excess property checks, but it only kicks in on fresh object literals)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does TypeScript not throw an error when the function argument type is mismatched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841687/why-does-typescript-not-throw-an-error-when-the-function-argument-type-is-mismat)

Comment: Also relevant: [Empty interface allow any object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42537727) | [Why can I avoid excess property check in typescript just by passing a reference to an object to a function rather than the object in its literal form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52852278) | [Why does TypeScript not throw an error when the function argument type is mismatched?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61841687) | [Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497299)