# why does an object variable not throw an error when direct object does

Tags: typescript

in the following code:

```
const styles = {
    a: 1,
    b: '100%',
    c: 'invalid',
  } as const

  const styleHolder: { a: number, b: string } = styles

  const styleHolder2: { a: number, b: string } = {
    a: 1,
    b: '100%',
    c: 'invalid',
  }
```

Why does `styleHolder2` throw an error on `c` while `styleHolder` does not. Is there anything I can do to get the same error on styleHolder?

[example in typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCeAbAphGBeGBvAUDfMAhgFwwCMANHgQEakDkZADEwKT1UEzAMCWYAN0KJeAEw7UAvkTShIUHNTnQ4UJMgASIRKOQAnUliKkwAVwC2NfRRh1Ve-gHMY0zAhQRF+ZbHebtunoATIbGMGaW1rak0A5gzq7Y1Pgk5Jy0DMxsElw8MPT8QiLi6ZJAA)

Comment: Please see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841687/why-does-typescript-not-throw-an-error-when-the-function-argument-type-is-mismat).  If it does not address your question, please edit this question to highlight the differences.